Variable address does not fall within the stack range in /proc/self/maps
I have a very simple program to test this:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int ss;
    int xx = system("cat /proc/self/maps | grep stack");
    printf("&ss=%p\n", &ss);
    return 0;
}

I compile and run this (on Linux, on an x86_64 cpu), I get something like this:
7ffc63ee7000-7ffc63f09000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
&ss=0x7ffe3e13d8a0

If you do the math, you see that 0x7ffe3e13d8a0 does not fall within the  7ffc63ee7000-7ffc63f09000 range. No matter how many times I run this, this seems to be the case. I can't understand why.
I've seen a similar question on SO already: Address of local variable not within the address range of stack shown by smaps
The provided answers don't work for me:

obviously there are no threads in this program.
no coroutine style programming, longjmp, etc.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Just to clarify the reason I need to do this. I'm writing a conservative garbage collector, and I want to get the range of stack to scan, by obtaining the address of a variable in main and another in the current function.

The memory map produced by system("cat /proc/self/maps | grep stack") is not that of your program, but rather that of the cat process that opens the file /proc/self/maps.
You should construct the command line from the pid of your own process:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int ss;
    char cmd[64];
    snprintf(cmd, sizeof cmd, "cat /proc/%d/maps | grep stack", getpid());
    system(cmd);
    printf("&ss=%p\n", (void *)&ss);
    return 0;
}

Output:
chqrlie@linuxbox:~/dev/stackoverflow$ ./test
7ffd9ffb5000-7ffd9ffd6000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
&ss=0x7ffd9ffd368c

For your GC purpose, using /proc/self/maps would be OK since you would be opening the pseudo-file from the same process.  Note however that this feature is linux specific, other unix or posix systems might not offer it, have a different API to get the info or the info might not be available at all.
Here is an implementation with a single process:
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *fp = fopen("/proc/self/maps", "r");
    if (fp) {
        char buf[200];
        int ss;
        while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, fp)) {
            if (strstr(buf, "stack"))
                fputs(buf, stdout);
        }
        fclose(fp);
        printf("&ss=%p\n", (void *)&ss);
        return 0;
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open /proc/self/maps: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }
}

Also note another non obvious fact: in your test, you get different ranges for your process and cat, not so much because they are different processes, but mainly because the OS performs address space randomisation as a countermeasure against simple attack vectors.  The addresses are in separate virtual memory spaces, so they might have matched by coincidence and they probably would have on older 32-bit linux systems.

Okay, I feel a little stupid now! :D Thanks.

@Elektito: Don't... at first, I thought the map would be the shell processes' :)

This to add to the answer from @chqrlie and to demonstrate that he is correct in his assumption, I have inserted a small piece of code to read the /proc file myself, and feed the output to grep stack command, and this time it shows as required:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int ss;

    FILE *i = fopen("/proc/self/maps", "r");
    FILE *o = popen("grep stack", "w");
    if (!i || !o) {
        perror("fopen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    while ((ss = fgetc(i)) != EOF) {
        fputc(ss, o);
    }
    fclose(i); pclose(o);

    printf("&ss=%p\n", &ss);
    return 0;
}

and output:
7ffe36685000-7ffe366a7000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
&ss=0x7ffe366a3f54

system() calls /bin/sh to execute the command you specify, and the shell in turn executes cat, which is the stack you are showing.
